# Split a comma-separated record into its own rows

Tags: postgresql, string-splitting

I have the following table, named stores:

```
store_id INT
emails VARCHAR
```

That contains values:

| store_id | emails |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | user_1@example.com,user2@example.com |
| 2 | uswe3@example.com,user4@example.com |
| 4 | admin@example.com |

And I want to generate the following set:

| store_id | emails |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | user_1@example.com |
| 1 | user2@example.com |
| 2 | uswe3@example.com |
| 2 | user4@example.com |
| 4 | admin@example.com |

As you can see I want to split the emails field into a separate record containing only one email address.
Do you have any idea how I can do that?

So far I managed to create the following query:

```
select store_id,string_to_array(emails,',') from stores
```

But I don't know how I can split the `string_to_array` to its own row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [`UNNEST()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql_unnest-function.php) in conjunction with [`STRING_TO_ARRAY()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql_string_to_array-function.php) as follows (fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=740dc857d5c0c8a6605c4df8a25f8b7d)):

```
CREATE TABLE stores
(
  store_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  emails TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO stores
VALUES
(1, 'user_1@example.com, user2@example.com'),
(2, 'uswe3@example.com, user4@example.com'),
(4, 'user_1@example.com,user2@example.com');
```

And then run this query:

```
SELECT 
  store_id,
  UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(emails, ',')) AS email
FROM stores;
```

Result:

```
store_id    email
1   user_1@example.com
1    user2@example.com
2   uswe3@example.com
2    user4@example.com
4   user_1@example.com
4   user2@example.com
```

One word of caution - depending on how your emails are formatted in the string, you might want to use the [`TRIM()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-trim-function/) function to make sure that there are no preceding or trailing spaces in the emails (shown in fiddle).

You can dissect what's happening if you simply run:

```
SELECT 
  store_id,
  STRING_TO_ARRAY(emails, ',') AS email_array
FROM stores;
```

Result (see updated [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=740dc857d5c0c8a6605c4df8a25f8b7d)) - the emails are still just one record - UNNEST puts each separate element of the array into a different row!:

```
store_id    email_array
       1    {user_1@example.com," user2@example.com"}
       2    {uswe3@example.com," user4@example.com"}
       4    {user_1@example.com,user2@example.com}
```